# C++ visibility of inherited constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, using-declaration

When I use `using` like this why is the constructor inherited publicly?

```cpp
class Base {
int x;
public:
    Base(int x);
};

class Derived : public Base {
    using Base::Base;
};
```

I can now do:

```cpp
Derived d (2);
```

I thought that `using` declarations had the visibility of where they are situated. Here, it should be private.

From *The C++ Programming Language*:

> A name brought into a derived
>   class scope by a using-declaration has its access determined by the placement of the using-declaration;

Answer (score 6):

According to the C++17 Standard (10.3.3 The using declaration)

> 19 A synonym created by a *using-declaration* has the usual
>   accessibility for a *member-declaration*. **A *using-declarator* that names a
>   constructor does not create a synonym; instead,** the additional
>   constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to
>   construct an object of the corresponding base class, and **the
>   accessibility of the *using-declaration* is ignored**.