# Discrepancy concerning default constructibility

Tags: c++, c++20

Clang and GCC don't seem to agree about what makes a type default constructible. Is GCC wrong here? Is the formal definition of the standard not clear about this?

```
#include <concepts>

class base {
protected:
    base() = default;
};

struct der : base {
    using base::base;
    der(int) {}
};

der d; // constexpr base::base() is protected within this context
static_assert(std::semiregular<der>); // fails on GCC
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/jehrn7rvq)

---

JHBonarius and alagner have provided the requested information, referring to already existing sources that cover the details pretty well. For now, I think it's best to direct this question more towards Clang's deviating behavior. I've initiated the bug-reporting process and will post any follow ups here.

Comment: I don't know why it compiles on Clang... bug? It's kind-of weird to me that `using` the base default constructor re-enables the otherwise implicitly deleted default constructor. But if it's correct, it's still protected.

Comment: @JHBonarius you're basing your statement on the following excerpt from the standard, 10.3.3.2: "if the using-declarator names a constructor, it declares that the class inherits the set of constructor declarations introduced by the using-declarator from the nominated base class.", is that right?

Comment: @alagner You seem to know where it's in the standard, I don't, but yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ visibility of inherited constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695057/c-visibility-of-inherited-constructor)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 inheriting constructors and access modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015909/c11-inheriting-constructors-and-access-modifiers)

Comment: based on the dupe, it's a Clang bug... you can report it. Although I don't know exactly where and if there is any chance they will consider it.

Comment: Thank for providing the information that explains the observed behavior from this question. Let's find out if Clang acknowledges this defect or if they see things differently.

Answer (score 3):

As we discussed in the comments, seems GCC implements the standard right (though it seems counterintuitive):

C++ standard, 10.3.3.2

> **Each using-declarator in a using-declaration introduces a set of
> declarations into the declarative region in which the
> using-declaration appears.** The set of declarations introduced by the
> using-declarator is found by performing qualified name lookup (6.4.3,
> 13.2) for the name in the using-declarator, excluding functions that are hidden as described below. If the using-declarator does not name a
> constructor, the unqualified-id is declared in the declarative region
> in which the using-declaration appears as a synonym for each
> declaration introduced by the using-declarator. [ Note: Only the
> specified name is so declared; specifying an enumeration name in a
> using-declaration does not declare its enumerators in the
> using-declaration’s declarative region. — end note ] **If the
> using-declarator names a constructor, it declares that the class
> inherits the set of constructor declarations introduced by the
> using-declarator from the nominated base class.**

Note that [factory method](https://godbolt.org/z/5cvE8aEnP) works as expected.

EDIT: and it's been already asked and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57695145/4885321) ;)